# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Controller\SecurityController could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem when I try to use my public function resetPassword.
Back me this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Controller\SecurityController could not be converted to string

My User Entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $login;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $birthDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $adress;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $orders;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=City::class, inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $activationToken;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $resetToken;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLogin(): ?string
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    public function setLogin(string $login): self
    {
        $this->login = $login;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthDate(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthDate;
    }

    public function setBirthDate(DateTimeInterface $birthDate): self
    {
        $this->birthDate = $birthDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adress;
    }

    public function setAdress(string $adress): self
    {
        $this->adress = $adress;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrders(): ?Order
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

    public function setOrders(Order $orders): self
    {
        $this->orders = $orders;

        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($orders->getUser() !== $this) {
            $orders->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getUsername() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?City
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(?City $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActivationToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->activationToken;
    }

    public function setActivationToken(?string $activationToken): self
    {
        $this->activationToken = $activationToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getResetToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->resetToken;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $resetToken
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setResetToken(?string $resetToken): self
    {
        $this->resetToken = $resetToken;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My SecurityController:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\ResetPassType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Exception;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_Message;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\TokenGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;



class SecurityController extends AbstractController implements FormTypeInterface
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();


        /*if($this->isGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"))
        {
            return $this->redirectToRoute("main");
        }*/

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error]);
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/oubli-pass", name="app_forgotten_password")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserRepository $users
     * @param Swift_Mailer $mailer
     * @param TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator
     * @return Response
     */
    public function oubliPass(Request $request,
                              UserRepository $users,
                              Swift_Mailer $mailer,
                              TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator): Response
    {
        // On initialise le formulaire
        $form = $this->createForm(ResetPassType::class);

        // On traite le formulaire
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // Si le formulaire est valide
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // On récupère les données
            $donnees = $form->getData();

            // On cherche un utilisateur ayant cet e-mail
            $user = $users->findOneByEmail($donnees['email']);

            // Si l'utilisateur n'existe pas
            if ($user === null) {
                // On envoie une alerte disant que l'adresse e-mail est inconnue
                $this->addFlash('danger', 'Cette adresse e-mail est inconnue');

                // On retourne sur la page de connexion
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
            }

            // On génère un token
            $token = $tokenGenerator->generateToken();

            // On essaie d'écrire le token en base de données
            try{
                $user->$this->setResetToken();
                $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $entityManager->persist($user);
                $entityManager->flush();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->addFlash('warning', $e->getMessage());
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
            }

            // On génère l'URL de réinitialisation de mot de passe
            $url = $this->generateUrl('app_reset_password', array('token' => $token), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);

            // On génère l'e-mail
            $message = (new Swift_Message('Mot de passe oublié'))
                ->setFrom('ewen.launay889@gmail.com')
                ->setTo($user->$this->getEmail())
                ->setBody(
                    "Bonjour,<br><br>Une demande de réinitialisation de mot de passe a été effectuée pour le site Bikealinge.com . Veuillez cliquer sur le lien suivant : " . $url,
                    'text/html'
                )
            ;

            // On envoie l'e-mail
            $mailer->send($message);

            // On crée le message flash de confirmation
            $this->addFlash('message', 'E-mail de réinitialisation du mot de passe envoyé !');

            // On redirige vers la page de login
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
        }

        // On envoie le formulaire à la vue
        return $this->render('security/forgotten_password.html.twig',['emailForm' => $form->createView()]);


    }



    /**
     * @Route("/reset_pass/{token}", name="app_reset_password")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string $token
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function resetPassword(Request $request,
                                  string $token,
                                  UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        // On cherche un utilisateur avec le token donné
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['resetToken' => $token]);

        // Si l'utilisateur n'existe pas
        if ($user === null) {
            // On affiche une erreur
            $this->addFlash('danger', 'Token Inconnu');
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
        }

        // Si le formulaire est envoyé en méthode post
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            // On supprime le token
            $user->setResetToken(null);

            // On chiffre le mot de passe
            $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $request->request->get('password')));

            // On stocke
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();

            // On crée le message flash
            $this->addFlash('message', 'Mot de passe mis à jour');

            // On redirige vers la page de connexion
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
        }else {
            // Si on n'a pas reçu les données, on affiche le formulaire
            return $this->render('security/reset_password.html.twig', ['token' => $token]);
        }


    }
    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout", methods={"GET"})
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        // controller can be blank: it will never be executed!
        throw new Exception('Don\'t forget to activate logout in security.yaml');
    }




    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getRoles() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getPassword() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getUsername() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // TODO: Implement buildForm() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        // TODO: Implement buildView() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        // TODO: Implement finishView() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        // TODO: Implement configureOptions() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getBlockPrefix() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getParent() method.
    }

}
```

I think the problem come from $user line 166 in my SecurityController.

Comment: Maybe it's just a copy/paste error but why would you have a controller implement FormType?

Comment: Good question! I see public function a the end of my SecurityController who need FormInterface but there is nothing on it. Do you think i have to delete it?

Comment: the error message should contain the location of the error (stack trace)

Comment: I'm thinking what you needs to do is to work through some of the examples in the docs and get yourself a basic understanding of Symfony.  Controllers use forms but controllers are not forms.  Pretty sure the error message is coming from the form system trying to use the controller.

Comment: Yes it's my first symfony project im not understanding all symfony concept yet.